# Rest API Get method Replicate Response

Tags: apex

Hi I need to replicate a rest response. Kinda stuck on how I can pass the values since the response example is a type of array. Any help is much appreciated stuck with this for hours. I need help on how I can parse the 2nd response combined with the 1st response example.

This is my class

```
global with sharing class rest_ListRegistrantDevicesStub {
    private System.RestRequest restRequest;
    private System.RestResponse restResponse;

    global static void doGet(){
        System.RestRequest restRequest = System.RestContext.request;
        System.RestResponse restResponse = System.RestContext.response;
        restResponse.statusCode = ConstantsHTTP.RESPONSE_STATUS_CODE_OK;

        devices dv1 = new devices('C1234567890', Date.newInstance(2015, 03, 18), 'SG110', 'Device Nickname 1', false, new list<String>{'2015-03-18','2016-03-18','2015-03-09'},
            'Registered', 'bob@example.com', 2);

        devices[] devicesList = new devices[]{dv1};

         utl_Json.SetJsonRestResponse(restResponse, devicesList);


    }

        private class devices {
        public String serialNumber {get; set;}
        public Date registrationDate {get; set;}
        public String model {get; set;}
        public String additionalInfo {get; set;}
        public String productTypeName {get; set;}
        public Boolean isHidden {get; set;}
        public List<String> licenseExpiryDates {get; set;}
        public String managedByPartnerId {get; set;}
        public String managedByPartnerName {get; set;}
        public String managedByPartnerCountry {get; set;}
        public String managementRequestedByName {get; set;}
        public String managementRequestedByEmail {get; set;}
        public String scfmManagingStatus {get; set;}
        public String registrationStatus {get; set;}
        public String registrantEmail{get; set;}
        public Integer remainingDaysToAcceptRegistrantTransfer {get; set;}

        public devices(string serialNumber, date registrationDate, string model, string additionalInfo, Boolean isHidden, List<String>licenseExpiryDates, string registrationStatus,
            string registrantEmail, integer remainingDaysToAcceptRegistrantTransfer) {
            this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
            this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
            this.model = model;
            this.additionalInfo = additionalInfo;
            this.isHidden = isHidden;
            this.licenseExpiryDates = licenseExpiryDates;
            this.managedByPartnerId = managedByPartnerId;
            this.managedByPartnerName = managedByPartnerName;
            this.managedByPartnerCountry = managedByPartnerCountry;
            this.managementRequestedByName = managementRequestedByName;
            this.managementRequestedByEmail = managementRequestedByEmail;
            this.scfmManagingStatus = scfmManagingStatus;
            this.registrationStatus = registrationStatus;
            this.registrantEmail = registrantEmail;
            this.remainingDaysToAcceptRegistrantTransfer = remainingDaysToAcceptRegistrantTransfer;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what my response should look like:

```
        {"devices": [
          {
          "serialNumber": "C1234567890",
          "registrationDate": "2015-03-18",
          "model": "SG110",
          "additionalInfo": "Device Nickname 1",
          "isHidden": "false",
          "licenseExpiryDates":[
               {
                    "2015-03-18",
                    "2016-03-18",
                    "2015-03-09"
               }
            ],
          "registrationStatus":"Registered",
          "registrantemail": "bob@example.com",
          "remainingDaysToAcceptRegistrantTransfer":"2"
       },
       {
          "serialNumber": "C0987654321",
          "isHidden": "true",
          "scfmManagingStatus": "Approval pending",
          "managedByPartnerId": "001Q000000gEVXHIA4",
          "managedByPartnerName": "PartnerCompany",
          "managedByPartnerCountry": "United Kingdom",
          "managementRequestedByName": "John Doe",
          "managementRequestedByEmail": "john.doe@sophos.com"
          "registrationDate": "2015-03-18",
          "model": "SG110",
          "licenseExpiryDates":[
               {
                    "2015-06-18",
                    "2016-01-18",
                    "2015-09-09"
               }
            ],
          "registrationStatus":"Registered",
          "registrantemail": "bob_Smith@example.com",
          "remainingDaysToAcceptRegistrantTransfer":"1"
       }
    ]}
```

Comment: you haven't really provided an explanation in your code, besides, you do know why your Constructor is not defined? maybe you can help clarify step by step what you are attempting to do in your code and where exactly you are stuck? Please take some time to visit [ask] and take the [tour] in order to get familiar with the forum. Welcome to SFSE!

Comment: Your second parameter is `List<Asset>` (which isn't used at all); you must match the parameter count and type to the values in the parameters defined by the constructor.

Comment: @glls Well actually what I need to do is create a class where in I can create a response that look exactly like my response example. That part that I'm stuck is that I believe the response example is an array of device. Now I don't know how I can pattern my Parameters to handle an array. Meaning 2 types of device but different pattern of parameters. Any help will do thanks :)

Comment: @glls this is an rest get api btw :)

Comment: Also, your JSON is invalid. Please double-check the intended response value.

Comment: @sfdcfox What do you mean by my json is invalid?

Comment: `"licenseExpiryDates":[
           {
                "2015-03-18",
                "2016-03-18",
                "2015-03-09"
           }
        ],` is invalid; objects must have key-value pairs.

Comment: @sfdcfox Hi I updated my class to match the first response body. Now my problem is for the 2nd one. for my public class. I matched the parameters to the 1st response. But for the 2nd response what should I do and how can i call it?

Comment: Go to [JSON Lint](https://jsonlint.com/) and **verify** your JSON. You're not going to get the code to look like the JSON, because it's not valid JSON. Once you do that, you should consider just using [JSON2Apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) to generate the correct wrapper class(es) for you. After that, you should easily be able to construct your data.